# Slider content issue in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-type

Drupal: i am trying to create 3 sliders on a single page. for this purpose i am using two types of slider modules like jcarousal and galleria. The problem is when i upload images to the slider content type(separate content type created for each slider) the previous images disappeared on adding 8th or 9th image. this is occuring into sliders data/images. i am not getting this that what is the problem. it seems its not like sliders issue its something drupal's issue. can anybody help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check JS console , if you have conflict between js's modules

2 - Check classes and ids, if both use sames classes that an issue

3 - Let me know why think it's a Drupal issue and not js conflict ?

Comment: Thanks @Fky. But its not the JS issue. i sorted out. i was thinking drupal issue bcz i am using completely two different modules jcarousal and galleria. when adding images into galleria the images added for jcarousal disappear and vice versa. i've checked every kind of limit etc into view settings for each content type.(the imp thing is the images are going disappear but en EMPTY Div still remain there and slides out when click.)

Comment: I see what you mean , maybe try to hook file loading too see what goes wrong , or add JS sequence to fix this problem . I think you can't solved this problem with a pretty way :/